# How can you get the names of method parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

If I have a method such as:

```
public void MyMethod(int arg1, string arg2)
```

How would I go about getting the actual names of the arguments?
I can't seem to find anything in the MethodInfo which will actually give me the name of the parameter.

I would like to write a method which looks like this:

```
public static string GetParamName(MethodInfo method, int index)
```

So if I called this method with:

```
string name = GetParamName(MyMethod, 0)
```

it would return "arg1". Is this possible?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
public static string GetParamName(System.Reflection.MethodInfo method, int index)
{
    string retVal = string.Empty;

    if (method != null && method.GetParameters().Length > index)
        retVal = method.GetParameters()[index].Name;


    return retVal;
}
```

The above sample should do what you need.

Comment: Any ideas about making this work with a function where the arguments are supplied as a `params` array?

Answer (score 10):

Try something like this:

```
foreach(ParameterInfo pParameter in pMethod.GetParameters())
{
    //Position of parameter in method
    pParameter.Position;

    //Name of parameter type
    pParameter.ParameterType.Name;

    //Name of parameter
    pParameter.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

without any kind of error checking:

```
public static string GetParameterName ( Delegate method , int index )
{
    return method.Method.GetParameters ( ) [ index ].Name ;
}
```

You could use 'Func<TResult>' and derivatives to make this work for most situations

Comment: @TomAnderson - blindly copying code from the internet is asking for trouble too!

Answer (score 2):

`nameof(arg1)` will return the name of the variable `arg1`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx

Comment: I'm almost _entirely_ sure that the OP meant from  **outside** of the method.  All of the other comments, left eight years before yours, also seem to confirm that.