# Name of the constructor arguments in c#

Tags: c#, reflection

I've a requirement in which i need to get the variables names of the constructor in my class.
I tried it using c# reflection, but constructorinfo does not give sufficient information. As it only provides the datatype of the parameters but i want the names, ex

```
class a
{    
    public a(int iArg, string strArg)
    {
    }
}
```

Now i want "iArg" and "strArg"

Thanks

Comment: In which context do you need this?  Could you use .NET Reflector?

Comment: That requirement could run into a lot of problems. For instance, why would the compiler even keep the names, they just make the compiled code longer. Also what happens if you run the code through a confuscation? What possible reason could you have for this requirement?

Comment: [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation): it lives on.

Comment: Try to have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214086/how-can-you-get-the-names-of-method-parameters-in-c

Comment: maybe he is crafting self generating code that is inserted into the body of an existing constructor?

Comment: Just as one possible use case: I need it to avoid magic strings when using constructor parameters in Autofac registration. I got in some trouble recently because of an upper/lower case typo.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you call `ConstructorInfo.GetParameters()`, then you will get back an array of `ParameterInfo` objects, which has a `Name` property containing the name of the parameter.

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.name.aspx) for more information and a sample.

The following sample prints information about each parameter of class A's constructor:

```
public class A
{
    public A(int iArg, string strArg)
    {
    }
}

....

public void PrintParameters()
{
    var ctors = typeof(A).GetConstructors();
    // assuming class A has only one constructor
    var ctor = ctors[0];
    foreach (var param in ctor.GetParameters())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
            "Param {0} is named {1} and is of type {2}",
            param.Position, param.Name, param.ParameterType));
    }
}
```

The above sample prints:

```
Param 0 is named iArg and is of type System.Int32
Param 1 is named strArg and is of type System.String
```

Answer (score 5):

I just checked MSDN for your question. As I see any `ConstructorInfo` instance may provide you with a method `GetParameters()`. This method will return a `ParameterInfo[]` - and any `ParameterInfo` has a property **Name**. So this should do the trick

```
 ConstructorInfo ci = ...... /// get your instance of ConstructorInfo by using Reflection
 ParameterInfo[] parameters = ci.GetParameters();

 foreach (ParameterInfo pi in parameters)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(pi.Name);  
 }
```

you may check [msdn GetParameters()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx) for any additional information.

hth