# Need to get optional parameters from ConstructorInfo

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invoking methods with optional parameters through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421994/invoking-methods-with-optional-parameters-through-reflection)
>   [Name of the constructor arguments in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606515/name-of-the-constructor-arguments-in-c-sharp)

Right now I am constructing objects using reflection.  I am using this to fill out API documentation.  In many cases I want a non-default constructor, but sometimes they have optional parameters.  These optional parameters need to be overridden with a new object other than the default.  The problem is I cant figure out how to get them.  The normal parameters are easy with constructorInfo.GetParameters(), however it seems the optional do not come back.  Am I missing something here?

Sample code:

```
            ConstructorInfo[] constructorInfoList = type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            foreach (ConstructorInfo constructorInfo in constructorInfoList)
            {
                var parameters = constructorInfo.GetParameters();
                if (parameters.Count() > 0)
                {
```

Answer:  It turns out they do come back... this was user error.

Sample:

```
void Main()
{
    var ctors = typeof(Foo).GetConstructors();
    foreach(var ctor in ctors)
    {
        foreach(var param in ctor.GetParameters())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} Optional: {1}", param.Name, param.IsOptional);
        }
    }   
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string option1, string option2 = "")
    {
    }
}
```

Output:

Name: option1 Optional: False
Name: option2 Optional: True

Comment: I believe you mean "optional" and not "named."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: Are you talking about attribute properties?

Comment: Can you give an example of (the code of) a constructor for which `constructorInfo.GetParameters()` does not give you the information you want?

Comment: http://jonfuller.codingtomusic.com/2010/06/04/teaching-structuremap-about-c-4-0-optional-parameters-and-default-values/

Comment: yes optional, not named sorry.

Comment: Perhaps this might be the same solution?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421994/invoking-methods-with-optional-parameters-through-reflection

Comment: Ummm, why the -1?  Who ever did that should try to contribute... so far I dont see a good answer.  I am looking at Tom's link now...

Comment: Is this how your "bad" constructors look: `public MyClass(int required, int optionalInt = 10) { ... }` The parameter `optionalInt` is "optional" because it says `= 10`. Or are you in fact searching for attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate.  It appears that you can call the parameter, but have to set the values manually.

I found a similar problem here:

[Invoking methods with optional parameters through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421994/invoking-methods-with-optional-parameters-through-reflection)

Comment: Tom, thanks for the links.  It turned out that I was Reflecting over 2 classes named the same thing, one had them and one didnt... I didnt write all this code, so I had no clue this could have been the case.  The optional params do come back, and they do have an attribute that marks them.  Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See here, it works:

```
var parameterName =
    typeof(Foo)
    .GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) })
    .GetParameters()
    .Single().Name;

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string paramName)
    {   
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried also with optionals parameters, FW 4.0, it works.