# Equivalent of func_get_arg in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there an equivalent to [func_get_arg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php) (php) in C#?

> **func_get_arg ( int $arg_num ):**
>
> Gets the specified argument from a user-defined function's argument list.
>
> This function may be used in conjunction with func_get_args() and func_num_args() to allow user-defined functions to accept variable-length argument lists.

It basically means the index can be used to get the argument value...

Thanks

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214086/how-can-you-get-the-names-of-method-parameters-in-c

Comment: I don't know of anything off hand that does this inside the basic framework of c#.  There are some dependency injection frameworks that would support something similar to this.  It would be helpful to know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ask what you want to do, now how you want to do it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# is statically typed, so function signatures *matter*. You can't just call a method with any number of arguments, which really means there is no need for `func_get_arg`.

That said, you can get pretty close if you have a method such as this one:

```
void MyMethod(params object[] args)
{
    var indexOfArgument = 42; // or whatever
    var valueOfArgument = args[indexOfArgument]; // should also check array bounds
}
```

Of course if all your arguments are typed as `System.Object` there's not much you can do with them, but from a syntactic viewpoint it's close (plus, you could also have a method that accepts `params T[] args` for any type `T`).

Comment: @Darren: From MSDN: "The [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(v=VS.100).aspx) keyword lets you specify a method parameter that takes a variable number of arguments."

Answer (score 0):

in C# there's a method "__arglist()"
or you can easily make a function accept variable number of parameters like this

```
int Average(params int[] ints)
{
int total = 0;
foreach(int i in ints) // loop to the number of parameters
    total += i;
return (ints.Length > 0 ? total / ints.Length : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the purpose of func_get_arg in PHP is to have a variable number of arguments to a function. Here's the equivilent to that in C#:

```
public void Foo(string realArg, int anotherRealArg, params int[] variableArgs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("My real string argument was " + realArg);
    Console.WriteLine("My real integer argument was " + anotherRealArg);
    Console.WriteLine("And I was given " + variableArgs.Length + " extra arguments");
}

// Usage
Foo("Bar", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Within the method, `variableArgs` is a regular array. Before accessing it, you'll want to check its Length to be sure you don't get an IndexOutOfRangeException.