# Get the name of the parameter that is passed to function

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter)

I have this function.

```
public void AddVariable( String str)
{
    Response.Write(str); // will write the value of str
}
```

But I need to write the name of the string variable that is passed into the function.

For example:

```
String temp = "test Variable";
AddVariable(temp);
```

Here I need to get the **name** of the variable inside my function, Instead of **value**.

ie, I need to get '**temp**' inside my function, Instead of '**test Variable**'.

Is it possbile?

Comment: @rs, I tried that answer, But I could get only the name of variable as 'str', not the one I passed in

Comment: @AkhilSekharan : see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214086/how-can-you-get-the-names-of-method-parameters-in-c

Comment: @pRosper K, It is returning the parameter name, not the name of string I passed in. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the name of the variable inside the function ("str"), but you cannot get the name of the variable that was passed into the function unless you pass it in as a second parameter.

It doesn't make sense to get the name of the variable passed to the function because there may not have even been a variable if a literal was passed such as `AddVariable("test variable")`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need parameter name (possible from reflection) but rather a variable name that has been passed as a parameter. AFAIK, for all practical purpose, this is not possible for the code within the function.

On the other hand, it's as such possible to do the code analysis of all assemblies loaded in the app-domain and find all invocations to your method and then do the stack-walk to determine possible invocation so that you may able to nail the variable name in the calling method (again if there can be many invocations in calling method, making it difficult to guess the variable name and you have to then rely on IL offset etc) but its just too convoluted.

Perhaps, you can state the reason for such requirements, there can be some alternative. For example, you can get and log stack trace within your method code that can be used for say trouble-shooting.