# Get the name of parameters from a calling method

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project using C# .NET 2.0 (cannot use a higher version). I would like to get the name of the parameters of a method in a method called by the first one. If I call a method from the MyMethodsClass, I want to receive a string indicating which parameter is not valid, following some conditions indicated in the isValid method from the MyCheckClass class.

With the following code, I get a string that returns "Please check the 5 parameter" in case I would call the myMehtod(5,1,1). But I would like to obtain, "Please check the a parameter".

How could I do that?
Thank you!

```
public MyMethodsClass {

    public string myMethod (int a, int b, int c) {

        return MyCheckClass.isValid(a,b,c);
    }

    public string myMethod2 (int d, int e) {
        return MyCheckClass.isValid(d,e);
    }

}


//Other file
public class MyCheckClass {

    public static string isValid (params object[] parameters) {

            StringBuilder result= new StringBuilder();          
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
            {
                object p = parameters[i];
                //Some checks...
                if (p == null || p.Equals("") || p != 5)
                {                    
                    result.Append("Please check the " + p + " parameter");
                }
            }
            return result.toString();               
    }
}
```

Comment: To get this clear, if myMethod2 is called like this myMethod2(someValue, someOtherValue); you want to have the name 'someValue' and 'someOtherValue'. Or do you want 'd' and 'e' wich are in the signature of the method?

Comment: I want to have the names of the signature, yes. Like: "Please check the a parameter", "Please check the d parameter"

Answer (score 3):

You combine two things you already know how to do.

1. [How can I find the method that called the current method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171970/how-can-i-find-the-method-that-called-the-current-method)
2. [How can you get the names of method parameters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214086/how-can-you-get-the-names-of-method-parameters-in-c/214108#214108)

Comment: @Antonijn this is wat the OP wants. Please see my comment to the question and his reaction to it

Comment: Yes, I think this is what I want. I am going to test it. Thank you : )

Comment: I am afraid this is not enough. I cannot identify in the params array which parameters map to which arguments from the original function (for example, I could receive isValid(3,3,5), but inside the isValid method I do not know where this 5 comes from. I could get the original parameters name, but not the corresponding one.

Comment: The `i` variable tells you which parameter you are looking at.

Comment: Yes. Thank you Raymond. But at the first sight I did not consider that I could have some myMethod3 method with 7 arguments that calls the isValid method with only three of them, and this case makes it very messy as I would not have a way to know which of them were passed... I would need to pass a Dictionary mapping the variable name and its value, to isValid mehtod making it more difficult to use by other classes that would like to use the isValid method...

Comment: If you're going to be passing only a subset of the parameters, then you need to let `isValid` know which ones you passed. At that point, you may as well just pass the names directly since it's about the same amount of work. `MyCheckClass(new Parameter[] { { "a", a }, { "c", c }, { "e", e })`.

Answer (score 1):

These two line should do the job for you, perhaps need to adapt but should work ^^

```
        MethodInfo info = typeof (MyMethodsClass).GetMethod("MethodName");
        string name = info.GetParameters()[indexOfTheFaultyOne].Name;
```

Comment: @Antonijn Um, in the example, `a` is the name of the formal parameter in the declaration of `myMethod`. In the example give, the method was called as `myMethod(5,1,1)` and he wants to extract the `a` that corresponds to parameter `5`.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!