# Get parameter name only from given string

Tags: c#, string

```
string mystring = "Display(String type1, String type2, String art3, String ar4, String art5, String art6, String arg7)"
```

Get parameter name only from above string like **type1,type2,art5** etc..

How should i manipulate

Comment: You can't get the parameters after you've created the string. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: can you show the Display class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214086/how-can-you-get-the-names-of-method-parameters duplicate ?

Comment: [`nameof(type1)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof)

Comment: its a string not a class

Comment: can we apply regex to above string for finding parameters only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string mystring = "Display(String type1)";
            string mystringValue = @"'1'";

            string s = mystring.Replace("String", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty).Replace('(', ',');
            string[] s2 = s.Split(',');

            ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList(s2);           
            myArrayList.RemoveAt(0);

            string[] s3 = mystringValue.Split(',');

            List<PropertyInformation> list = new List<PropertyInformation>();
            int index = 0;
            foreach (string name in myArrayList)
            {
                PropertyInformation p = new PropertyInformation();
                p.Name = name;
                p.Value = s3[index];
                list.Add(p);
                index++;
            }
```